# How to check if a number is greater than another number inside useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Js being difficult to me >:|

```
export default function Timer() {
  const [timer, setTimer] = useState(10000);

  useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(() => {
      if (Number(timer) > Number(6000)) {
        setTimer((prevCount) => prevCount - 100);
      }
    }, 100);
  }, []);
  
  console.log(timer);
```

Why doesn't this timer stop counting down when it hit 6000?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wont need `setInterval`. Let `useEffect` run only when the timer changes and this is done by passing the `timer` as argument.

This [link](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#explanation-why-effects-run-on-each-update) describe how to optimize `useEffect`

```
const [timer, setTimer] = useState(10000);

function setTimerToNewValue() {
  setTimer(timer - 100);
}

useEffect(() => {
  if (timer > 6000) {
    setTimerToNewValue();
  }
}, [timer]);
console.log(timer);
```

In this example `useEffect` will execute as soon as `timer` changes.

Here is another implementation with `setInterval`

```js
function setTimerToNewValue() {
  setTimer((timer) => timer - 100);
}

useEffect(() => {
  let z;
  if (timer > 6000) {
    z = setInterval(() => {
      setTimerToNewValue();
    }, 1000);
  }

  return () => clearInterval(z);
}, [timer]);
```

[Demo Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-h41aa5)

Comment: Pardon my confusion. `useEffect` should just render and rerender until it hits 6000 like this, right? And we dont know how long in between renders so its not a timer, right? becuase it isnt consistent?

Answer (score 1):

if you have to use timer you can use this code

```js
export default function Timer() {
    const [timer, setTimer] = useState(10000);
 
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(timer)
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
            if (timer>6000)
            setTimer(timer => timer - 1000);
        }, 1000);
        return () => clearInterval(interval);
    })
}
```